# Adding commas in to extended numbers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm wanting to add commas in to break up numbers within my iOS application.

For example:

- Change 1000 into 1,000
- Change 10,000 into 10,000
- Change 100000 into 100,000

And so on...

What is the most efficient way of doing this, and safe-guarding against numbers post decimal point too?

So for example,

- 1000.50 should return 1,000.50

My numbers at the moment are Ints, Doubles and Floats - so not sure if I need to manipulate them before or after converting to Strings.

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to format your doubles as integers if there is no fraction digits? I mean if you have a Double 1000 do you want to return 1,000 or 1,000.00?

Comment: I assume for your second example you meant to say "Change 10000 into 10,000"? (your before and after are the same.)

Answer (score 2):

The Foundation framework (which is shared between iOS and MacOS) includes the `NumberFormatter` class, which will do exactly what you want. You'd configure a number formatter to include a `groupingSeparator`. (Note that different countries use different grouping separators, so you might want to set the `localizesFormat` flag to allow the `NumberFormatter` to change the separator character based on the user's locale.

Here is some sample code that will generate strings with comma thousands separators and 2 decimal places:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()

// Set up the NumberFormatter to use a thousands separator
formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
formatter.groupingSize = 3

//Set it up to always display 2 decimal places.
formatter.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = true
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2


// Now generate 10 formatted random numbers
for _ in 1...10 {

    // Randomly pick the number of digits
    let digits = Double(Int.random(in:1...9))

    // Generate a value from 0 to that number of digits
    let x = Double.random(in: 1...(pow(10, digits)))

    // If the number formatter is able to output a string, log it to the console.
   if let string = formatter.string(from:NSNumber(value:x)){
        print(string)
    }
}
```

Some sample output from that code:

```
356,295,901.77
34,727,299.01
395.08
37,185.02
87,055.35
356,112.91
886,165.06
98,334,087.81
3,978,837.62
3,178,568.97
```